# How to paste from clipboard to Excel using a condition to split the data into separate columns?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I paste data from clipboard to Excel using a condition to split the data into 2 separate columns?

For example I have this in my clipboard:

8:01
17:01
7:56
17:02
7:56
17:00
7:53
17:01
7:56
17:01
7:57
17:02
7:56
17:01
7:56
17:00
7:56
17:02

And I want to paste the values that are below 10:00 into column A and the ones that are bigger than 10:00 into column B so that the result will be:

A           B
1    8:01    17:01
2    7:56    17:02
3    7:56    17:00
4    7:53    17:01
5    7:56    17:01
6    7:57    17:02
7    7:56    17:01
8    7:56    17:00
9    7:56    17:02

Only thing I managed till now is paste them all into one column, then use the filter, and manually copy and paste the values into two different columns

[image]

Comment: I have tried Excel filter, custom paste wizard, and some functions with notepad++ but no luck I'm not really sure where to start

Comment: Could you explain how the data gets into the clipboard in the first place? The answer may be to get the data into excel in a different way. Also, is the data always formatted as small number, carriage return, large number and then repeat...?

Comment: I originally copy the data from worker's attendance report (PDF) and paste into notepad, then I copy from notepad, so that the data comes clean into the clipboard. And yes, the data is always sorted that way

Comment: Can you use vba? This would be my answer...

Comment: Yes I guess I can use VBA question is how

Comment: My answer will replace the pasted values but still give the result required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way... This code will also do the pasting. You don't have to do it manually :)

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, startRowA As Long, startRowB As Long
    Dim i As Long

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    startRowA = 1: startRowB = 1

    With ws
        '~~> Using this as you are copying it from Notepad~~~~
        .Activate
        .Range("A1").Select
        .PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
        '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow - 1 Step 2
            .Range("C" & startRowA).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value
            startRowA = startRowA + 1
        Next i

        For i = 2 To LastRow Step 2
            .Range("D" & startRowB).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value
            startRowB = startRowB + 1
        Next i
    End With

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

[image]

**FOLLOWUP**

The problem apparently was the Hebrew version of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Paste the following method in a module or the worksheet containing data

```
Option Explicit
Sub SplitCellsForValue(ByVal splitValue As Integer)
Dim source As Range
Dim cell
Dim currentValue

Dim rowForColumn1Ctr As Integer
Dim rowForColumn2Ctr As Integer

Dim column1Ctr As Integer
Dim column2Ctr As Integer

Dim maxRowsAfterSplit As Integer

rowForColumn1Ctr = 1
rowForColumn2Ctr = 1

'** Put your source range here
Set source = Range("A1:A7")

maxRowsAfterSplit = CInt(source.Rows.Count / 2)
For Each cell In source.Cells
    currentValue = Val(Replace(cell.Text, ":", ""))

    If currentValue < splitValue Then
        Range("B" & rowForColumn1Ctr) = cell.Text
        rowForColumn1Ctr = rowForColumn1Ctr + 1
    Else
        Range("C" & rowForColumn2Ctr) = cell.Text
        rowForColumn2Ctr = rowForColumn2Ctr + 1
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Usage: (you can call the following from immediate window)

```
SplitCellsForValue 1000
```

In the sample above, it takes data from A1:A7 (change this for your case) and splits the content by given parameter (value:1000) to `SplitCellsForValue` and puts the content in column "B" and "C" - which you can change.

Note: Value 1000 = 10:00 with : removed from it.

Comment: looks perfect though I cant get it to run! I create a new module, paste the code into it, then run with F5 and nothing happens!

Answer (score 0):

If you paste the following vba code and run it on the sheet you have pasted the values you'll end up with tow columns as requested.

```
Sub cell_to_column()

    Dim lastrow as long, currentpaste as long
    'find last row
    lastrow = Columns("A:A").Find("*", range("A1"), xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).row
    currentpaste =1

    'cycle through all cells in column a
    For each a in range(cells(1,1), cells(lastrow,1))

        If len(trim(a.value)) >= 5 then 'if found 10:00 or larger

            'if a value if found copy its value over 
            Cells(currentpaste, 2).value = a.Value
            A.value = ""
            Currentpaste = currentpaste +1

        End if

    Next

    'remove all blank cells
    range(cells(1,1), cells(lastrow,1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp

End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write a macro, do the following:

1. Paste the value in A1 as you are doing.
2. On `B1`, type `=OFFSET(A1,ROW()-ROW($A$1),0)`
3. On `C1`, type `=OFFSET(A1,ROW()-ROW($A$1)+1,0)`
4. Format `B1` and `C1` into Time. Otherwise, it will appear as a number.
5. Select `B1` and `C1` then paste down.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pasting into Notepad (ie go back a step first), paste into Word, Insert > Tables –Table, Convert Text to Table and choose Columns: 2 before pasting into Excel.